# What is the keyboard shortcut to have LastPass generate secure password and fill in new password fields?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lastpass

What is the keyboard shortcut to have LastPass generate a password and fill in password fields? I am using the Chrome extension.

Answer (score 4):

Alt G creates the password but doesn't fill it. I found it on the lastpass website: http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/extension-preferences/hotkeys/

Comment: It actually fills the input in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut for password generation on Windows is `Alt+g`.

You can see all of the so-called Hotkeys in the options:

- Right-click on the lastpass icon
- Click options
- Choose `Hotkeys`
- Set any keyboard shortcuts.

On a Mac there is no default shortcut for password generation. You would need to set your own.